Multiple Outbound Calls resulting in errors
Within in our SF organization, I need to send API calls to another platform when certain records are updated in Salesforce. I've successfully created triggers and apex classes (utilizing @future) to achieve the ability to make API calls. However, now I'm running into the issue when multiple users update different records, the corresponding API calls will fail because they're being sent at the same time (calls need to have half second delay between each). Does anyone have recommendations or experience in using queueable or schedulable to create a queue for all outbound api calls (i.e. if two records are updated at the same time and 2 api calls need to be made that it will queue one after the other)
I'm new to developing in Salesforce, and any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!!!

What is the error message?

The API returns a 401 (unathorized) , so I need a way to be able to stagger the outbound API calls

That may be a different issue, not related to multiple call in short timeframe. You may need to get access token again before calling the api again.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

This API doesn't generate a token to use, uses basic authentication...it is a psuedo rest api doesn't require a token before making an actual call...

here is from developer of API on 401s:
Regarding multiple calls: Your font end application should handle interfacing with the API 1 call at a time with at least 500 MS (half second) between calls.
If the API receives multiple calls simultaneously, the first call will process while the second will 401. You also run the risk of locking your API due to database conflicts if both calls are accepted by the server and try to engage resources at the same time.

When you need more control over the timing of callouts, you'll want to place them into a queue of some kind. Depending on how long each API call takes, Salesforce is capable of delivering dozens or even hundreds of API calls per second. A typical implementation is to create a Custom Object that keeps track of records you want to send, and a Queueable or Batchable class that runs periodically to send out those calls in a controlled manner.
In your specific case, it could look something like this:
public class CalloutHandler implements Queueable {
  Boolean doApiCall(Message__c message) {
    // Deal with API callout here
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Message__c[] messages = [SELECT Payload__c FROM Message__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending' LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE];
    Long timeStamp = DateTime.now().getTime();
    for(Message__c message: messages) {
      if(doApiCall(message)) { // Returns true when okay
        message.Status__c = 'Sent';
      } else { // Or some other logging mechanism?
        message.Status__c = 'Failed';
      }
      // busy loop to wait for 500ms
      while(DateTime.now().getTime()-timeStamp < 500);
      // Reset the timer
      timeStamp = DateTime.now().getTime();
    }
    // Save the results
    // Note: this must be the last step, because we cannot callout after DML
    update messages;
  }
  if(messages.size() > 0) {
    System.enqueueJob(this); // go again
  }
}

Your trigger/automation simply needs to create Message__c records and save them, then call the Queueable. The Queuable itself uses a locking mechanism to prevent duplicate calls, so calling it from a trigger is fine.
Actual implementation will depend on specifics, but this should be enough to get you started. You may need to adjust the maximum query size, timeout in ms, etc, according to your needs.

So, in my current setup if a record is created a trigger fires an apex class that constructs the body of the API call (json) would I pass this to the queueable class and then have a seperate class to make API calls?

@IanLock You don't pass it directly to the queueable--you save the payload to a record, then call the queueable, which in turn retrieves it from the database. This will allow records that trigger the mechanism at about the same time to be bundled into a single queueable execution, which controls the wait time between calls.

So if I had multiple objects they would add the components of an API call to the custom object...then would a trigger on the new custom object just fire when new records are inserted to the queueable class? would I put the queueable class on a schedule? Again, thank you for your help

@IanLock That would probably work. The queueable can be called directly from a trigger if you want near-real-time updates.
